# Как избавиться от сохранения старых версий документов в Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Пользуемся Logstash для синхронизации с БД MySQL. Крон стоит , условно, на каждые 5 секунд (пока что), каждый раз при синхронизации, elastic создает новую версию документа, и получается так что он просто не затирает старые версии - они остаются, а объем базы Elastic'a растет каждые 5 секунд, существуют ли какие-то способы удаления старых версий?

**Elasticsearch 7.3**

---

P.S.: Для большей внятности, есть 278 записей, они синхронятся каждые 5 секнуд, т.е. через 20 секунд будет 4 версии каждого документа, и база эластика вырастает в 4 раза, было `300kb`, через 20 секунд уже `1200kb`. Как затирать старые версии документов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был предельно прост. Logstash видимо не воспринимает camelCase, т.к. в конфигурации было прописано:

```
tracking_column => "updateTime"
```

Проблема решилась так:

```
tracking_column => "updatetime"
```

Скорее всего потому что ES и прочее используют  стиль написания `snake_case`.